# VBA run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to adjust an existing excel file (xlsm) of an old colleague.

Basically it are a bunch of forms (different sheets) where you can have several input lines and each input line is its own datapoint. There is a button to add another input line to the sheet.

The code behind the button is defined on each sheet in the VBA editor and the actual function which is called by all these buttons is a module.

The problem is that for two sheets the button works fine and for three other sheets the button gives the error in the title.

The code behind the button is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
theName = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim var As Integer
var = Range("H3").Value
For i = 1 To var
    InsertRowMacro (theName)
Next i
End Sub
```

and the beginning of the code in the module is:

```
Sub InsertRowMacro(sheetName)

'first unprotect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

rangeName = "range_" & sheetName
oorzaakName = "oorzaak_" & sheetName
olmName = "OLM_" & sheetName
Set test = ActiveWorkbook.Names
totalRange = ActiveWorkbook.Names(rangeName).RefersToR1C1
```

The error is thrown on the final line of this code block. As far as I can see there is no difference between the sheets but my VBA knowledge is limited and the old colleague is ofcourse not available.

Could somebody give me a hint? What could be a possible problem? What could I check?

Comment: Are all names defined in that Excel?

Comment: I would check the name manager (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4) as FunThomas said, ensuring the names I'm using (rangeName) exists.

You should probably debug it (step through) and see that variables values actually make sense. Error msgs in VBA are typically useless.

Comment: thank you both. I had never heard of the name manager! But this is indeed the solution. You are also correct that VBA errors are useless because I am now getting exactly the same error on a totally different line. But for now I am confident I will be able to solve that one. If one of you wants to turn it into an answer I am happy to accept it.